# \\{ in a doc string: what does it mean/do?

Tags: help, doc-strings

What does this backslash syntax mean?

```
(defun elfeed-search-mode ()
  "Major mode for listing elfeed feed entries.
\\{elfeed-search-mode-map}"
  (interactive)
```

Comment: It's \\{, not just two backslashes, and it's in a doc string, not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

This form expands to a summary of a keymap.

From [(elisp) Keys in Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Keys-in-Documentation.html):

> `\{MAPVAR}` 
>       stands for a summary of the keymap which is the value of the
>        variable MAPVAR.  The summary is made using `describe-bindings`.